# Запуск внешних скриптов в php, как сделать это асинхронно?

Tags: php, exec

Нужно запустить ffmpeg из php скрипта. Использую функцию shell_exec,
всё работает, но заметно подвисание скрипта особенно на больших файлах. Можно ли как-то выполнить скрипт асинхронно и чтобы интерфейс не подвисал и не ждал выполнения внешней программы?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.popen.php).

```
$res = popen('myprogram', 'r');
if (!$res)
  pclose($res);
```